# Custom fields with Mandrill Form Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-contactform

Is it possible to add custom fields to a contact from that is using the 
[MandrillForm Plugin](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/mandrillform)?

I need to add a field for phone

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code for the plugin, it doesn't look like it.

You'd either need to make a [feature request](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries/issues) or fork the plugin, add the functionality yourself and make a pull request.